# RxBluetoothKit Code Pattern for Multiple Stage Bluetooth Commands

Tags: swift, rx-swift, rxiosble

I've started using RxBluetoothKit with good results for a peripheral we are developing. It works quite well and I am able to perform the transactions we need.

I have a design pattern question. We have a couple of commands where our API includes multi-step commands. For example, the App writes a command start code, the Peripheral confirms with an ACK, then the App writes the command, waits for an ACK, issues another command, waits for another ACK, etc. This can go on until the App issues a command stop code, which will be at some indeterminate point in the future — when the user tells the app to stop, for example.

Is there an appropriate coding idiom or pattern in the Rx world for accomplishing this? I am new to Rx in general, and am curious what might be the simplest, cleanest implementation of something of this sort.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Details as always depend on your very specific use case. I like to think about Rx as stream based building blocks which needs to be connected to model your business logic.

There is one example how it may look like:

```swift
enum DeviceService: String, ServiceIdentifier {
    case myService = "ffff"

    var uuid: CBUUID {
        return CBUUID(string: self.rawValue)
    }
}

enum DeviceCharacteristic: String, CharacteristicIdentifier {
    case startCharacteristic = "0001"
    case stopCharacteristic = "0002"
    case ackCharacteristic = "ffff"
    case command1Characteristic = "0003"
    case command2Characteristic = "0004"

    var uuid: CBUUID {
        return CBUUID(string: self.rawValue)
    }

    var service: ServiceIdentifier {
        return DeviceService.myService
    }
}

let peripheral : Peripheral? = nil

// Some internal command 1
let command1 = peripheral!.writeValue(Data(bytes: [0xff, 0xfe]),
                                      for: DeviceCharacteristic.command1Characteristic,
                                      type: .withResponse)

// Some internal command 2
let command2 = peripheral!.writeValue(Data(bytes: [0xdd, 0xee]),
                                      for: DeviceCharacteristic.command2Characteristic,
                                      type: .withResponse)

func batchCommands(commands: [Observable<Characteristic>]) -> Observable<Characteristic> {

    let commandsWithAck = commands.map { command in
        return command.flatMap { characteristic in
            return peripheral!.monitorValueUpdate(for: DeviceCharacteristic.ackCharacteristic).take(1)
        }
    }

    let start = peripheral!.writeValue(Data(bytes: [0x01]),
                                            for: DeviceCharacteristic.startCharacteristic,
                                            type: .withResponse)
    let stop = peripheral!.writeValue(Data(bytes: [0x00]),
                                           for: DeviceCharacteristic.startCharacteristic,
                                           type: .withResponse)

    return start.concat(Observable.concat(commandsWithAck)).concat(stop)
}

// Call it:
let subscription = batchCommands(commands: [command1, command2])
    .subscribe(onNext: nil, onError: nil, onCompleted: nil, onDisposed: nil)
```

There, `start` and `stop` observables can be changed to monitor user's behaviour and emit items when actual start/stop action should took place.

Comment: Thank you for this. One point that maybe I should have made is that the Service on the device side is a UART service, so there are two Characteristics — TX and RX. In this case, I writeValue with the appropriate command data on TX and then monitor the RX for the result. What I'm curious about is how to cleanly monitor RX after writing to TX and then appropriately handle the ACK (or NACK or error) and then proceed with any commands after start. What I can see from your example is that the batch goes from `start` to `ack` where `ack` is monitored. But does monitorValueUpdate block before `stop`?